# BeautifulSoup - extract number

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to learn how to scrape the web, but I have some problem getting my code to work. The number I want to extract is 77.80 from the code below. The problem I have is to find something that is unique enough to find the information(the place). can you help me with the right code. Thanks in advance!

```
    </td>

            <td class="small">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

                    <td align="center" nowrap  valign="center" class="small">
                    <a alt="Utvald" class="small" href="javascript:QT('/se/skandia/funds/chosen.aspx?tab=5&cid=0P0000T35O&lang=SV&curiso=SEK&country=SE&clientattributes=8&lastpage=Sök fond&LastPageURL=/se/skandia/quickrank/index.aspx?tab=RSLTS|lang=SV|univ=SE1|country=SE|curiso=SEK|mec=|cat=-1|search=|sortby=Custom_4|sortorder=ASC|PageNo=1|Firstletter=','0P0000T35O','600')"  onmouseout="status=''; return true"><img src="../read/im/sigillsvartsmall_FFFFFF.gif" border="0" alt="Utvald av Skandia" height="12" width="9"/></a>
                </td>

            <td class="small">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

                <td align="right" nowrap  valign="top" class="small">
                    77.80                           
                </td>

            <td class="small">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

                <td align="right" nowrap  valign="top" class="small">
                    <!--<img src="../read/im/valueSEK.gif" align="texttop" height="10" width="22">-->
                    SEK
                </td>

            <td class="small">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

                <td align="right" nowrap  valign="top" class="small">
                    1.4
                </td>

            <td class="small">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

                <td align="right" nowrap  valign="top" class="small">
                    0.5
                </td>

            <td class="small">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

                <td align="right" nowrap  valign="top" class="small">
                    2.7
                </td>

            <td class="small">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

                <td align="right" nowrap  valign="top" class="small">
                    6.6
                </td>
```

Comment: There's not enough information to generalize what you want.  Do you want the first number after a cell with an image?  Do you want the largest number?  Right now, all we know is that you want the number 77.80.  If all you want is the number 77.80, then the answer's very easy!

Comment: If you haven't gotten far enough in your webscraping I would suggest the use of lxml. Then you can use xpath which is great. Also, according to stackoverflow.com/questions/11465555/can-we-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup, it may well be faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to find text you wanted. This just looks for the first `td` that has `class='small'` and `valign='top'`.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
tds = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'small', 'valign': 'top'})
the_td = tds[0].text.strip()
```